# How to remove pattern containing blank space and special characters in sed

Tags: linux, script, regex, sed

How to remove following words from a text file:

1. `DEFAULT ('')`
2. `DEFAULT ((0))`
3. `DEFAULT (((1)/(1))/(1900))`
4. `DEFAULT (getdate())`

I am not able to delete above four pattens using sed.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I could not able to remove all the four pattens from the file.

Comment: Please could you [edit] the question, remove that parts that aren't needed, and describe what help you need.  From what you are saying, 1,2 and 4 are not relevent?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with `sed` or generally with a regular expression. Identifying a closing parenthesis requires a parser which you might implement in `awk`, `python`, `perl` or whatever language.

See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524548/regular-expression-to-detect-semi-colon-terminated-c-for-while-loops/524624#524624

Comment: After some hard work :) Got solution using sed.Solution is : sed  -i "s#DEFAULT ('')##g" filename
sed  -i 's/DEFAULT\s((0))//g' filename
sed  -i 's#DEFAULT\s(((1)/(1))/(1900))##g' filename
sed  -i 's#DEFAULT\s(getdate())##g' filename

Comment: Please post your solution as your own answer, it is unreadable as a comment.